# Free memory on FPS system

Tags: javascript, canvas, frame-rate, lag, kineticjs

I start on KineticJS (and on Canvas) and i'm creating a small game for learn...
Right now, I have just 2 layers :

- First with a map composed by Kinetic.Image
- Second with the last time who game as draw.

I want refresh display X time per second but after 20 or 30 times the game are really slow.. And it's the same when I flood event click ( who launch the draw function too)...
Moreover, i can see in the second layer : the old text are never clean, the new are added on top... :/

```
   var stage;
   var layers = {};

   var CANEVAS_WIDTH = 800;
   var CANEVAS_HEIGHT = 600;

   var MAP_WIDTH    = 10;
   var MAP_HEIGHT   = 10;

   var MAPPING_WIDTH = 150;
   var MAPPING_HEIGHT = 88;

   var LEFT_X   = 0;
   var LEFT_Y  = MAP_WIDTH*MAPPING_HEIGHT/2;
   var TOP_X   = MAP_WIDTH/2*MAPPING_WIDTH;
   var TOP_Y   = 0;

   var VIEW_X   = 0;
   var VIEW_Y  = 0;

   var CURSOR_X = 6;
   var CURSOR_Y = 0;

   var images = {};

   function loadImages(sources, callback)
   {
       var loadedImages = 0;
       var numImages = 0;

       // get num of sources
       for (var src in sources) 
           numImages++;

       for (var src in sources) 
       {
           images[src] = new Image();
           images[src].onload = function(){
               if (++loadedImages >= numImages) 
                   callback();
           };
           images[src].src = sources[src];
       }
    }

    function getMouseInfo(mousePos)
    {
        var info = {screen_x   : mousePos.x, 
                    screen_y   : mousePos.y,
                    mouse_x      : mousePos.x+VIEW_X,
                    mouse_y      : mousePos.y+VIEW_Y-LEFT_Y,
                    onMap      : 0,
                    map_x      : -1,
                    map_y      : -1};

       map_x = -(info.mouse_y - ((LEFT_Y * info.mouse_x) / TOP_X)) / MAPPING_HEIGHT;
       map_y = -(-info.mouse_y - ((LEFT_Y * info.mouse_x) / TOP_X)) / MAPPING_HEIGHT;

       if(map_x >= 0 && map_x < MAP_WIDTH && map_y >= 0 && map_y < MAP_HEIGHT)
       {
           info.map_y = parseInt(map_y);
           info.map_x = parseInt(map_x);
           info.onMap = 1;
       }
       return info;
    }

    function draw()
    {
        drawMap();
        drawFPS();

        stage.add(layers.mapLayer);
        stage.add(layers.fpsLayer);
   }

   function drawFPS()
   {         
       layers.fpsLayer.clear();
       var fps = new Kinetic.Shape(function(){
           var date = new Date();
           var time = date.getTime();

           var context = this.getContext();
           context.beginPath();
           context.font = "12pt Calibri";
           context.fillStyle = "red";
           context.fillText("FPS : "+time, 10, 20);
       });

      layers.fpsLayer.add(fps);
   }

   function drawMap()
   {
       var x=0,y=0;

       layers.mapLayer.clear();

       var s = new Kinetic.Shape(function(){
            var context = this.getContext();
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(0, 0, CANEVAS_WIDTH, CANEVAS_HEIGHT);
            context.fillStyle = "#000";
            context.fill();
            context.closePath();
       });
       layers.mapLayer.add(s);


       for(x=0; x<MAP_WIDTH; x++)
          for(y=0;y<MAP_HEIGHT; y++)
          {
              var img = new Kinetic.Image({
                    image: ((x==CURSOR_X && y==CURSOR_Y)?images.testMapCursor:images.testMap)
              });
              img.x = x*MAPPING_WIDTH/2 + y*MAPPING_WIDTH/2 - VIEW_X;
              img.y = (MAP_WIDTH-1)*MAPPING_HEIGHT/2 - x*MAPPING_HEIGHT/2 + y*MAPPING_HEIGHT/2 - VIEW_Y;

              layers.mapLayer.add(img);
           }

    }

    function changeCursorPosition(cursor_x, cursor_y)
    {
        CURSOR_X = cursor_x;
        CURSOR_Y = cursor_y;

        draw();

    }

    function initStage()
    {   
        layers.mapLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        layers.fpsLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        draw();
    }

      /*
       * INIT
       */   

    window.onload = function(){   

       stage = new Kinetic.Stage("container", <?=CANEVAS_WIDTH;?>, <?=CANEVAS_HEIGHT;?>);

       stage.on("mousemove", function(){
           var mouseInfo = getMouseInfo(stage.getMousePosition()); 

           if(mouseInfo.onMap)
               document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
           else
               document.body.style.cursor = "default";
       });

       stage.on("mousedown", function(){
           var mouseInfo = getMouseInfo(stage.getMousePosition()); 

           if(mouseInfo.onMap)
               changeCursorPosition(mouseInfo.map_x, mouseInfo.map_y);
      });

      var sources = {
          testMap         : "testMap.png",
          testMapCursor   : "testMapCursor.png"
      };

      loadImages(sources, initStage);

   };
```

Sorry, my english are realy bad.

Thank all.

Comment: English tip: it's spelled "canvas", not "canevas".

Answer (score 0):

I know someone who is trying out KineticJS. I haven't used it myself, so I apologize that I cannot provide more specific help.

Unfortunately, it is very difficult to get good performance with canvas, and it depends greatly on the browser. Last I checked, Opera 12 and IE 9 performed significantly faster than other browsers, since their 2D rendering is 3D accelerated (using OpenGL and Direct3D, respectively)

I am not sure if this applies to KineticJS, but one technique you can use to improve performance with canvas is to use multiple canvas elements, and transform their positions rather than blitting on a single surface.

I've been pretty happy with the results I've gotten using Jeash, which is wired into NME's command-line tools. The development is similar to working with Flash, but it will create an HTML5 Canvas application using your code. The same application will also be able to publish to Windows, Mac, Linux, iOS, Android, webOS and Flash, as either native C++ and OpenGL, or as SWF bytecode. This gives you a lot of options for providing the best experience for each user.

http://www.haxenme.org